# Symfony QueryBuilder setParameters replacing values

Tags: symfony, parameters, query-builder

I have a problem with query builder.
When i delete parameters and give variables in select it returns good values;

Values for parameters:

dbpetrolcolumn = petrol_type

dbpricecolumn = price

dbcitycolumn= city

```
$qb = $conn->createQueryBuilder();
                $result =$qb
                    ->select(':city,:petrol,:price')
                    ->from($form['dbtable']->getData(), 'p')
                    ->setParameters([
                        'petrol'=>$form['dbpetrolcolumn']->getData(),
                        'price'=>$form['dbpricecolumn']->getData(),
                        'city'=>$form['dbcitycolumn']->getData(),
                    ])
                    ->execute()
                    ->fetchAll();
                var_dump($result);
```

and it returns this array:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'city' => string 'city' (length=4)
      'petrol_type' => string 'petrol_type' (length=11)
      'price' => string 'price' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'city' => string 'city' (length=4)
      'petrol_type' => string 'petrol_type' (length=11)
      'price' => string 'price' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'city' => string 'city' (length=4)
      'petrol_type' => string 'petrol_type' (length=11)
      'price' => string 'price' (length=5)
```

Good one should look like

```
array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'city' => string 'Katowic' (length=4)
          'petrol_type' => string 'Pb95' (length=11)
          '4.50'
```

Answer (score 0):

This really suggests bad design, if you need to supply arbitrary columns names and replace them in your prepared statement. May I suggest you alter your DB design in order to make columns names constant (query-wise)?

If the above does not suit you, you will need to fallback to manually sanitizing your inputs (e.g. column names) and concat them to your query. Contrary to this, your can still utilize prepared statements to your `WHERE` predicate query section.

Kinda patchy: you *could* create a `VIEW` on top of your table and then let your app talk to that view...

Something like this:

```
$validColumnNames = [ ... ];
$validTableNames = [ ... ];

$inputColumns = [ 
    $form['dbpetrolcolumn']->getData(),
    $form['dbpricecolumn']->getData(),
    $form['dbcitycolumn']->getData()
];

$inputTableName = $form['dbtable']->getData();

if (!in_array($inputTableName, $validTableNames, TRUE)){
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Go away!");
}

foreach ( $inputColumns as $col ){
    if ( !in_array($col, $validColumnNames, TRUE){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Go away!");
    }
}

$query = sprintf("SELECT %s, %s, %s FROM %s",
    $inputColumns[0], 
    $inputColumns[1], 
    $inputColumns[2], 
    $inputTableName
);
```

Then you could continue with `PreparedStatement` and apply `WHERE` section (if needed)

Hope this helps...

Comment: ok but :) db is not mine I get this data (dbname,host ,citytable,petroltable etc) from user. Then I can't modify db.

Comment: Ah, I expected that :) In that case, apply very strict input validation / sanitization...

Comment: I've added the example for validation, but it is far for ideal (didn't try running it to be frank). Remember, do not shoot yourself in a foot (of blow your leg off entirely) with some nasty SQL injection :)

Comment: Thanks for support :)
Maybe some mastermind show how to use parameters normally there :D
About injection hmm i think this not be a problem because user manually typing db connect data :)